# How do i assign 2 values from different tables into 1 variable name as foreign key using Entity Framework-Code First

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, ef-code-first

I'm confused with the foreign key concept. I'm trying to arrange the key relationships in each database class according to the Code First concept in Entity Framework.

I have 3 tables: a, b and c.

Table a has `aId` as primary key(PK), table b has `bId` as PK, table c has `cId` as primary key. The relationship between table is:

- a-b : many-to-one,
- a-c : one-to-one,
- b-c : one-to-many

Table a has a variable refid which can hold both bId or cId values.

```
<ForeignKey("bId")>
Public Property refid As b

<ForeignKey("cId")>
Public Property refid As c
```

refid is now highlighted red saying that

> the properties cannot overload each other because they differ only by
>   return types.

What am i doing wrong?

**EDITED**

```
public class a

    public property aId as String  // Primary key

    Public Property refid As String

    <ForeignKey("refid")>
    Public Property b As b

    <ForeignKey("refid")>
    Public Property c As c

End Class


public class b

    public property bId as String    // Primary key

    // b Navigation Property
    public property aCol As ICollection(Of a)

End Class


public class c

    public property cId as String  // Primary key

    // c Navigation Property
    public property aCol As ICollection(Of a)

End Class
```

Comment: You gave two properties the same name with same overloads in one class which is not possible. You also cannot define one navigation property for two foreign keys. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22284959/2882256).

Comment: Its actually because i'm creating the variables according to the database fields. And the logic is that those two share the same field. so thats why i thought that it had to share the same variable as it is in the database...i'm still a bit confused..based on my understanding, User class(as the one party in the one-to-many relationship) will hold the ICollection as the navigation properties. While, the inverse property and foreign key will be assigned to the BlockedUser and Contact class(representing the many party in the relationship) as the navigation properties to link between User and...

Comment: ...BlockedUser and Contact. Is this correct? The confusion is this part in Slauma's answer: [InverseProperty("BlockedContacts")]
public virtual User Contact { get; set; } I don't see any ContactId in User..am i misunderstanding the concept or is that a typo? Isn't it supposed to be Contact Contact?

Comment: From what i can see in that post, they created 2 different variables(turned into foreign key), each variable for each of the primary keys from the 2 tables. So where did they merge those 2 foreign keys into 1 variable? its like each foreign key has its own variable and own Navigation Property. because in my case, my table has a field 'refid' which stores either one of those foreign keys(bId or cId from b class and c class respectively). I'm so sorry if i'm imposing on you but i'm truly stumped.

Comment: @AlexB. I've edited my question. Could you please check if its viable? I forgot to notify you in my previous comments.

Comment: Seems fine at first glance. Give me some time, I will check it carefully asap.